# VideoView inside Fragment, onPreparedListener never called (android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I'm using VideoView to play a video, at first I put this in an activity and worked perfectly fine, but since I'm trying to put the functionality in an API, I have to put the video in a Fragment. I did that and coded an Activity that uses the fragment but it seems that the OnPreparedListener that I set on the VideoView is never called (I saw this debugging and because my progress dialog never disappears from the screen). I'm trying to figure out why. Here is my code:

Fragment code:

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {

private VideoView videoView;
private int position = 0;
private MediaController mediaController;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName()
            + "/" + R.raw.vid_ej;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment, container, false);

    if(mediaController == null){
        mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
    }

    videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Progreso");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando video...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    mediaController.show();

    try {
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("msg", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.pause();
                    //mp.start();

                }
            });

            videoView.seekTo(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                videoView.start();
            } else {
                videoView.pause();
            }
            /*
            if (position > 0) {
                Log.e("msg", "Position>0: " + position);
                videoView.pause();
                //mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
                Log.e("msg", "currentposition: " + videoView.getCurrentPosition());
            }
            else {
                //mediaPlayer.start();
            }*/
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    position=videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    outState.putInt("Position", position);
    videoView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        videoView.seekTo(position);
    }
}
```

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center">
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main activity that uses the fragment:

```
public class PruebaVideoMain extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.prueba_video_main);
 }
}
```

Main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/videoFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="example.com.probando.videoPlayer.VideoFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/video_fragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please change class="example.com.probando.videoPlayer.VideoFragment" to **android:name="example.com.probando.videoPlayer.VideoFragment"**

Comment: @Sunhee I just tried that, didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing this line in the main layout:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

for

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```